# AngularJS Routing Case Sensitivity

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, case-sensitive

I haven't been able to find a straightforward answer to this, which leads me to believe that it's something really really simple. Either way, here I go.

All of the calls in my $routeProvider work great, but are case sensitive. Here's a code sample:

```
config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', { controller: 'TmpCtrl', templateUrl: '/app/home.html' }).
        when('/foo', { controller: 'TmpCtrl', templateUrl: '/app/foo.html' }).  
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```

What do I need to add so that '/Foo', '/fOO', '/FoO', etc, all redirect to the same path?

Comment: Maybe this question would be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994324/angularjs-base-href-case-sensitive

Comment: It seems related, but I don't fully understand what I need to do to make this work from me. My assumption is that I would need to pull a specific script and include it in my project, but I'm not sure what else needs to be added.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There is an option you can pass to $routeProvider to toggle case sensitivity:

```
config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', { controller: 'TmpCtrl', templateUrl: '/app/home.html' }).
        when('/foo', { controller: 'TmpCtrl', templateUrl: '/app/foo.html', caseInsensitiveMatch: true }).  
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```

Comment: This works on version 1.2.2. Thanks a lot @John, this should be marked as answer!

Comment: You'd think there would be a config for $routeProvider to do this et al. I guess not?

Comment: @RJB There is: $routeProvider.caseInsensitiveMatch = true;