# Angular.js application requring URL to be case sensitive in IIS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iis

I have been developing an Angular.js application that is going to be deployed on IIS. For some odd reason if I use:

http://myserver.com/appname

The application loads properly.

If I use:

http://myserver.com/APPNAME

The application does not load at all. I thought IIS was NOT case-sensitive. Any idea what would cause something of this nature?

FYI, we are using html5mode on the routing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS Routing Case Sensitivity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824687/angularjs-routing-case-sensitivity)

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with routing as the path to the base of the application in the angular routing is "/" which has no text to be car sensitive about. It is more of an IIS issue I believe.

Comment: my mistake then. after some googling i ended up on this link. it may help
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/085109da-209e-4332-abd9-9454156be880/how-to-turn-off-case-sensitive-urls-in-iis-on-win-2008-r2-sp1?forum=winserver2008appcompatabilityandcertification