# AngularJS caseInsensitiveMatch not working

Tags: angularjs

I referred to [AngularJS + Base Href Case Sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994324/angularjs-base-href-case-sensitive) this thread. As per that I should be using 1.1.5 however still I am having the problem.

Angular is still returning the same error.Here is what i am doing.

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' , caseInsensitiveMatch : true });
```

My base Href is `/appname/`. Now anyone can enter URL like `AppName` or `appName` or any combination.

Right now routing works only when URL contains what is given in base href.

Anything I am doing wrong ?

Here is output in console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null angular.js:5637
matchUrl angular.js:5637
$$parse angular.js:5704
$get angular.js:6120
invoke angular.js:2931
(anonymous function) angular.js:2771
getService angular.js:2891
invoke angular.js:2909
(anonymous function) angular.js:2771
getService angular.js:2891
invoke angular.js:2909
(anonymous function) angular.js:2775
forEach angular.js:148
createInjector angular.js:2775
resumeBootstrapInternal angular.js:1001
bootstrap angular.js:1017
angularInit angular.js:977
(anonymous function) angular.js:16872
jQuery.Callbacks.fire jquery-1.8.2.js:974
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith jquery-1.8.2.js:1082
jQuery.extend.ready jquery-1.8.2.js:406
DOMContentLoaded jquery-1.8.2.js:83
```

Comment: did you try to change angular ver?

Comment: I am using 1.1.5.Which should I be using?

Comment: I can see `caseInsensitiveMatch` in the angular.js

Answer (score 1):

caseInsensitiveMatch is not in the documentation for Angular 1.1.5.  It seems best to upgrade and see if that solves the issue.