# Case sensitive url issue - Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angular-ui-router

I am working on an MVC 4 application using Angular JS (version 1.3.2). I am facing a strange issue of URLs acting case sensitive.

For e.g. I have this working URL,
http:// www.abc.com/**a**pp2/products

but if I change this URL to
http:// www.abc.com/**A**pp2/products then it fails. I get 404 page not found error.

Here I have virtual path property of the MVC project set to 'app2'.
Also, in the base HTML page, I have a base tag as,

```
<base href="/app2"/>
```

Everything works fine if I keep this base path as lowercase, but the moment I change it to uppercase, it fails.

I googled and found many guys complaining about similar issue occurring when using Angular JS.

Below are the links I most useful,

[AngularJS + Base Href Case Sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994324/angularjs-base-href-case-sensitive)

[AngularJS caseInsensitiveMatch not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249130/angularjs-caseinsensitivematch-not-working)

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4056

But all these solutions seems to be targeting some specific version of Angular JS and doesn't work in my case (I modified my router.js file and it didn't work).

Any ideas how can I solve this issue?

Is this issue resolved in latest version of Angular JS?

Comment: according to base tag your angular app is in `app2` directory. Angular routing only manages any part of url after that. Sounds like you have server config issue not angular

Comment: Is there any configuration which manages case sensitivity? I haven't any stuff like that...Also I haven't made any special changes on server side. It's just regular default settings...

Comment: That explains it, you need to configure server routing to allow using html5mode in your angular routing

Comment: I am really sorry for this. But I am not getting your point. Can you help me with the code which I should be adding and where?

Comment: if you don't understand the implications don't use html5mode in angular routing or read the docs about server side implications

Comment: Thanks for the rude reply. I found out the solution...

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is case sentisitive by default, you need to force the case insensitive by adding `caseInsensitiveMatch`param to your `routeProvider`config

```
config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', { controller: 'TmpCtrl', templateUrl: '/app/home.html' }).
        when('/foo', { controller: 'TmpCtrl', templateUrl: '/app/foo.html', caseInsensitiveMatch: true }).  
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```