# Angular html5mode prevents links outside of base href to be loaded

Tags: angularjs, html

My setup is as follows:

I have a website for which I would like one of the pages to be handled by angular (javascript heavy one).
I have set base href **for this specific page only** as `<base href="/myangularpage">`

This page is being controlled over only by url params. There is only one page like this. No routing. I handle the state using url parameters only. Example url: `http://domain.com/myangularpage?param1=2&param2=3`

However this page contains links to some other pages which should be followed and not handled by angular. Like `/external-page`. By external I mean they are on the same domain but have different base.

However setting up html5mode causes those links to be "push stated".

According to the docs and the answer to [Angularjs Normal Links with html5Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837704/angularjs-normal-links-with-html5mode) `/external-page` has a different base so should not be handled by angular.

But the problem is it is!

Tried adding `/` to the base url but I got a meaningless [exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261782/typeerror-cannot-read-property-replace-of-undefined). I don't want the trailing slash in my page url so this isn't a real solution anyway.

**EDIT:**

So it seems it works when my base url has a trailing slash and I serv the page with an url which contains the slash. But I don't want the slash as it is a single page only.

Comment: I deleted my answer since I realised you are probably linking to a page on the same domain, just outside the angular app. Is that correct?

Comment: I've had this same issue in the past. We are using ui-router, so I just created new states with the url set to the "/external-page" (an html file) and the template pointing to that html file. It's a pretty dumb workaround, but it works for us...