# Angular html5 mode not working in apache

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess

I had an angular app with this folder strucure

```
app
 --app.js
controllers
 --controller.js
services
 --services.js
css
img
index.html
.htaccess
```

my index.html had

```
<base href="/">
```

and my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

And everything worked fine

Now I want to change to this folder structure

```
public
  --app
    --app.js
  --controllers
  --services
  --css
  --img
  --index.html
.htaccess
```

I've changed to index.html base to

```
<base href="/public/">
```

and my .htaccess to

```
DirectoryIndex public/index.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

And now html5 mode is not working, though if I turn off html5 mode the app works...What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe your hrefs need 'public/'  prepended to it?

Comment: my hrefs are ok, all the files are loaded properly but it got a js error `angular.js:11651Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261782/typeerror-cannot-read-property-replace-of-undefined It has something to do with ui-router