# TypeError : Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, base-tag, html5mode

**Overview :**

I would like to redirect the visitor on a default page(index.html) inside the directory structure to display when a directory is accessed using `.htaccess` file(as of now current directory index.html is loading).

But When I turn on `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` in my angular application getting below error.

**Console Error :**

[image]

**Directory structure of Application :**

```
public_html
  --prod
    --public
      --app
        --controllers
        --directives
        --services
        --app.config.js
    --index.html
  --.htaccess
.htaccess
```

**public_html** `=>` **.htaccess :**

```
DirectoryIndex prod/public/index.html
```

This `.htaccess` is used to redirect the visitors on a application page (`prod/public/index.html`) directly by using domain name, as of now when user visit the domain the current directory(`public_html`) index.html is loading.

**public_html** `=>` **prod** `=>` **.htaccess :**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /prod/public/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /prod/public/#/$1 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/prod/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

**prod** `=>` **public** `=>` **index.html :**

```
<base href="/prod/public/">
```

Everything working fine If i removed `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` from my `app.config.js` file.So, when I comment out the `$locationProvider` code, everything works fine in `#` mode. I can get to `/#/abc`, etc. without issue. As soon as I put the `$locationProvider` parts back in, nothing happen.

Related issues on Stack Overflow with no success :

[$locationProvider.html5Mode(true) issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28859276/locationprovider-html5modetrue-issues)

[Angular html5 mode not working in apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38154044/angular-html5-mode-not-working-in-apache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `public_html => .htaccess` have this rule instead:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?$ prod/public/index.html [L]
```

then `public_html => prod => .htaccess` should have this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ public/index.html [L]
```

Comment: can you please explain these lines more briefly..I want the `urls` without `#`.

Comment: I hadn't tried to change much in your shown rules. Major issue I found was that `DirectoryIndex prod/public/index.html` is not correct and won't rewrite domain requests to `/prod/public/index.html` as `DirectoryIndex` just sets default handler files. Unfortunately I don't know much about angularjs so I can help only on Apache side. Test out my updated rule and see if that fixes your problems.

Comment: for some reason, i got the error net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on my localhost :(. any idea why this can happen?

Comment: @RaduVlad: I don't know your htaccess and your configuration. I suggest you create a separate question so that I can try to resolve it.

Comment: @anubhava: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39165096/htaccess-for-subfolder-of-angularjs-app-with-html5-mode