# .htaccess for subfolder of AngularJS app with HTML5 mode

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, html5mode

**Overview :**

I have an AngularJS application that uses **`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`** and it is served from an Apache server. Until now I used the source code to be accessed from the others and I just needed a redirect to index.html for the angularJS's HTML5 mode. So I had this for the `.htaccess` file for my `/app` folder.

**.htaccess :**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

**Modifications :**

I then added Grunt for minifying the whole solution that is generated in the `/dist` folder of the app(so now the minified solution is found at /app/dist). I would now like to route the whole traffic of my app to the minified version, without making the users change the link. So, in practice I would like to redirect every call from /app to /app/dist.

**Directory Structure now :**

```
app
    dist
        minified versions(css,html,js)
```

I tried using some conditions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory) in /app's .htaccess and moved the other .htaccess file in /app/dist, but with no success. I don't even know if the two can be combined in this way. I know I can use the dist folder as /app instead, but I wouldn't really want this, as /app is a repo and it is way easier to keep it updated. So how can I manage to achieve this with redirecting?

Also, as a second thing, is it possible to put a flag somehow so I let alpha users use the normal (not-minified) version for better debugging?

**Update:**

I added a sample project for this [here](https://github.com/radumvlad/angular-dist-redirect). I just kept the initial .htaccess files that i showed above and you can check that both versions(`/test` and `/test/dist`) work as stated above. Also, it probably has some unused code and dependencies, but I just cut the other parts from my project(don't judge :D).

For this I used the initial configuration with AngularJS 1.4.8 that could generate some errors like the one stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261782/) and [here](http://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11091). Feel free to update the AngularJS version to 1.5.8(the last stable release of Angular 1), but take in consideration the comments on [Cosmin Ababei's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39218569/1787172) as well. Also, the project uses npm for installing grunt(and other extensions for grunt), bower for angular and some other basic components and grunt for building the minified version(actually, it's just concatenating resources in same files for now). If you need to change the dependencies, please don't forget to run `bower install`. If you want to regenerate the dist folder, don't forget to run `npm install` and `grunt build`.

Comment: Can't you just use RewriteRule ^ dist/index.html [L]

Comment: But the resources are in dist folder as well.

Comment: Ah right, I overlooked that. Well, at this point I'm reduced to Googling myself, but this looks like it could work for your situation (it's about wordpress, but it's a good clean description): https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Pointing_your_home_site.27s_URL_to_a_subdirectory

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?localhost/app$
 RewriteRule ^(/)?$ dist [L]

this isn't working

Comment: Do you already a .htaccess inside `app/dist/`? If yes then show it here? What rules are you using to serve minified resources?

Comment: @anubhava I tried moving the old .htaccess to `app/dist/`, but for the moment that file is empty.

Comment: But them I am unclear how is minified resource being served?

Comment: well, if i just use `localhost/app/dist/` and the `.htaccess` that I presented in the post, everything works. I can just remove all my `app` content and copy the `app/dist` content into the `app` folder and it would work(of course, I also have to change the base href)

Comment: I will try to make a sample version somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that inside the `/dist` directory you have `index.html` with the updated URLs which point to the minified resources and the correct `<base>` tag. Note that **the `<base>` tag must point to the `/dist` folder** - just append `/dist` to the value you're using for the *uncompressed* `index.html` and you'd be fine.

With those things in order, here's the updated `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Don't rewrite files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the ALPHA_USER cookie is set, serve the uncompressed files
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ALPHA_USER [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

# Rewrite everything
RewriteRule ^ dist/index.html [L]
```

You'll notice two things:

- I've removed `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d` as most likely you don't need to serve whole directories
- I've added the `ALPHA_USER` cookie which would redirect the users to the uncompressed files. This cookie can have any value you desire.

Comment: It still doesn't work, I receive the following error: "app.src.js:20938 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined". I'm trying to debug and come here if I get what's wrong. Also, yes, in the dist folder the base tag has /dist and if i enter on localhost/app/dist with the old .htaccess in /dist folder everything works.

Comment: After some research on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261782/typeerror-cannot-read-property-replace-of-undefined and https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11091, I updated the angular to 1.5.8 and it works. Unfortunately, now I get to access the http://localhost/app/dist by link, probably the angular redirects me. Can I somehow hide this? Or should I set the url by hand in the angular app, described as a possibility in the first stackoverflow link?

Comment: The `<base>` url must point to the absolute url on your server. For example, if by now you had your app at `www.my-domain.com/app`, you must update it `www.my-domain.com/app/dist`. I'm not sure I understand how would you have `localhost` in your URL.

Comment: Well, for the moment i'm trying to host it on my local machine with an apache server. 
The problem I have now is that when I enter on `http://localhost/app/` I get redirected to `http://localhost/app/dist/login` instead of `http://localhost/app/login`. This happens with both `<base href='http://localhost/app/dist/'/>` and `<base href='/app/dist/'/>` in the index file.

Answer (score 0):

**Inside public_html `=>` /app `=>` .htaccess try this :**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ dist/index.html [L]
```

**Note :** HTML **`<base>`** tag should be point to the dist folder. I hope this solution will work as per your expectations.

Comment: fails with ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Comment: @RaduVlad see this post i was also having same issue few days back..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39026692/typeerror-cannot-read-property-replace-of-undefined

Comment: thanks, but i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong :(.